# Errors running Tensorflow on Windows with Python 3.7.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

**PROBLEM REGARDING TFLEARN AND PYTHON 3.7.4**
i believe that my code is fine but i am facing tflearn OR TENSORFLOW  issue in my python 3.7.4 how can i solve it?

[image: 1st image is here]

[image: 2nd image is here]

Comment: [Stack Overflow Discourages screenshots of code, errors & data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).  It is likely, the question will be downvoted, for containing unnecessary screenshots.  By using screenshots, you are discouraging anyone from assisting you.  No one wants to retype your stuff, from a screenshot, and screenshots are often, not readable.

Comment: Tensorflow does not currently support Python 3.7 on Windows.

Comment: The error is quite clear, you need to download the NLTK resources. The tensorflow stuff are not errors, just deprecation warnings.

Comment: Welcome to SO; please see why [an image of your exception isn't helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshots you have put in here, looks like tensorflow does not have any issue, it is just showing you warnings.

The error you have got is because nltk requires a library punkt. Please download it using

```
nltk.download('punkt')
```

inside the python console and it should solve your issue.